# Talagrand's inequality for the discrete cube

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

Talagrand showed that if $f$ is a convex $1$-Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if $\mu$ is a product of probability measures supported over the interval, then $f$ has Gaussian concentration w.r.t. to $\mu$:
$$
P(\vert f - E_{\mu}f\vert > \epsilon) < C \exp(-c\epsilon^2)
$$
for some absolute constants $c$ and $C$.

I would like to understand to what extent convexity is necessary in the special case where $\mu$ is the uniform measure on the discrete hypercube $\{0,1\}^n$. What are "representative" counterexamples if convexity is not assumed?

Comment: Will you provide a more precise statement or a reference for an appropriate version of Talagrand's inequality? Wikipedia has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talagrand%27s_concentration_inequality but that does not have an explicit Lipschitz hypothesis. The comment there, "this provides insufficient context for those unfamiliar with the subject", applies here too.

Comment: edited the question accordingly

Comment: @MattF. the wikipedia version is an equivalent form of the same inequality

Comment: Any function on $\{0,1\}^n$ can be extended to a "piecewise affine" convex function on $[0,1]^n$, and if I am not mistaken, this extension does not increase the Lipschitz constant. So it appears that for this particular $\mu$ one can completely drop the assumption that $f$ is convex.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, Can you provide a reference that such extension will not increase Lipschitz constant? I am asking this because I think if you would take a convex envelope  then the Lipschitz constant can increase. It may be some sort of Kirszbraun theorem but I do not remember any convexity assumptions...

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili: Good point: after re-considering what I wrote, I realise I was wrong. The Lipschitz constant *can* increase, by a factor that depends on the dimension $n$ – if I am not mistaken again, it is equal to $\sqrt{n}$. That would agree with your comment to Yuval Peres's answer, right?

Comment: Let $f : \{0,1\}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$, and for $x = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}) \in \{0,1\}^{n}$, let $D_{j}f(x) = \frac{f(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{j}, \ldots, x_{n}) - f(x_{1}, \ldots, 1-x_{j}, \ldots, x_{n})}{2}$. Put $|\nabla f|^{2} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} |D_{j}f(x)|^{2}$. Then if $|\nabla f|\leq 1$ on $\{0,1\}^{n}$ then $P(|f-\mathbb{E}f|>t) \leq Ce^{-ct^{2}}$ for all $t\geq 0$. See for example Corollary 4.2 in Ben-Efraim--Lust--Piquard https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702233.pdf .

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, Yes, I think so. So if one would try to construct a counterexample, one would need to take $1$-Lipschitz functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ whose "discrete gradient" on the Hamming cube is large. One such example would be $f(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})=x_{1}+...+x_{n}$ but this is not 1-Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, however it is 1-Lipschitz on the cube $\{0,1\}^{n}$ with respect to Hamming distance. So, maybe, one may need to adapt this example somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> there is no convexity assumption needed there.

Nevertheless  here is a counterexample of $1$-Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ which fails to satisfy concentration inequality on the Hamming cube $\{-1,1\}^{N}$ as $N$ goes to infinity.

Take $N$ to be even. Let 
$$
A = \left\{ (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{N}) \in \{0,1\}^{N}\, : x_{1}+\ldots+x_{N}\leq \frac{N}{2}\right\}.
$$
Next, define a function

$$
f(x) = \inf_{y \in A} \| x-y\|_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}
$$
Since $f$ is the distance function to a nonempty subset it follows that $f$ is $1$-Lipschitz (an exercise).

On the other hand notice that $f(x) = \sqrt{\max\{x_{1}+\ldots+x_{N} - \frac{N}{2},0\}}$ on $\{0,1\}^N$.  Then as $N$ goes to infinity we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(|f & -\mathbb{E}f| > N^{1/4}) \\ & = P\biggl(\biggl|\sqrt{\max\{\frac{(2x_{1}-1)+\ldots+(2x_{N}-1)}{\sqrt{N}},0\}} \\ & \qquad\qquad - \mathbb{E}\sqrt{\max\{\frac{(2x_{1}-1)+\ldots+(2x_{N}-1)}{\sqrt{N}},0\}} \biggr|>\sqrt{2} \biggr) \\ & \to P\left( | \sqrt{\max\{\xi, 0\}} - \mathbb{E} \sqrt{\max\{\xi, 0\}}|>\sqrt{2}\right)>10^{-10},
\end{aligned}
$$
where we used the central limit theorem, and $\xi$ is the standard normal Gaussian $\xi\in N(0,1)$.

Comment: Shouldn't there be square roots appearing in the limit as well (if so it's a detail)? Nice example anyway, wouldn't have expected that even the variance can get that large.

Comment: Yes there should be square roots, I will fix it, thank you. This detail is not important because it will only change the number $\frac{1}{10^{6}}$ which is till again nonzero. I will put $10^{-10}$ just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Very nice example! I edited it so that the big display fits my screen, and I also added a note that the inequality $f(x) \geqslant \sqrt{\max\{\ldots\}}$ only holds on $\{0,1\}^N$; hope you do not mind this edit.

Answer (score 7):

Talagrand's inequality is more general. The inequality you ask about is 
Mcdiarmid's bounded-difference inequality (see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob_martingale and McDiarmid, Colin (1989). "On the Method of Bounded Differences". Surveys in Combinatorics. 141: 148–188), which is a direct consequence of the Hoeffding-Azuma  inequality. there is no convexity assumption  needed there.  McDiarmid's bound (which leads to weaker concentration) is essentially sharp for functions that are Lipschitz in the $\ell^1$ metric, which is often the most relevant to combinatorial applications; in that case convexity is not needed and does not help: Consider $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum_i x_i$.  Requiring Lipschitz in $\ell^2$  is a much stronger requirement, which also leads to better concentration for convex functions and I now understand that was the assumption of interest to the OP.

Comment: But Mcdiarmid's bounded-difference inequality gives the bound $P(|f-\mathbb{E}f|>t) \leq C e^{-ct^{2}/n}$ since $|f(x_{1}, \ldots,x_{j}, \ldots  x_{n})-f(x_{1}, \ldots, 1-x_{j}, \ldots, x_{n})|\leq 1=c_{j}$, $\sum c_{j}^{2} =n$. But the question is with bound independent of $n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: McDiarmid's bound is essentially sharp for functions that are Lipschitz in the $\ell^1$ metric, which is often the most relevant to combinatorial applications; in that case convexity is not needed and does not help. Requiring Lipschitz in $\ell^2$ is a much stronger requirement, which also leads to better concentration for convex functions. I will edit my answer to reflect this.